# The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided

Tags: sql-server, restore

```
Restore database Currency
from disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Currency.bak'
go
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943106/sql-server-error-the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are-provided/29943219 Was already answered here.

Comment: Hey guys, is not with thumbs down that we welcome people in a community. @muhammad, try to be more consistent with your question next time. BTW there are 2 questions on dba.stackexchange and 1 on StackOverflow related to this error but none provides Pinar's query that I posted. So I believe this is a legit question and a legit reply.

Comment: A downvote can indicate a lack of research - which appears to fit this situation. A simple search on "sql server msg 3132" will find many discussions about the error and how to address it. The posted link does exactly the same. A downvote is not an attack on someone's character. Upvotes should not be used as some sort of reward or participation trophy.

Answer (score 0):

You think you have to restore the file `Currency.bak` but in fact that backup was taken in two parts, probably:

- `Currency.bak`
- `Currency2.bak`

So you need the second file.

[This query](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/04/22/sql-server-fix-msg-3132-level-16-media-set-2-media-families-1-provided-members-must-provided/) will give you the second part of the backup:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(max)
SET @DatabaseName = N'SQLAuthority'
USE msdb;
SELECT DISTINCT t1.NAME
    ,t3.[media_set_id]
    ,t6.family_sequence_number
    ,t6.physical_device_name
    ,(datediff(ss, t3.backup_start_date, t3.backup_finish_date)) / 60.0 AS duration
    ,t3.backup_start_date
    ,t3.backup_finish_date
    ,t3.type AS [type]
    ,CASE
        WHEN (t3.backup_size / 1024.0) < 1024
            THEN (t3.backup_size / 1024.0)
        WHEN (t3.backup_size / 1048576.0) < 1024
            THEN (t3.backup_size / 1048576.0)
        ELSE (t3.backup_size / 1048576.0 / 1024.0)
        END AS backup_size
    ,CASE
        WHEN (t3.backup_size / 1024.0) < 1024
            THEN 'KB'
        WHEN (t3.backup_size / 1048576.0) < 1024
            THEN 'MB'
        ELSE 'GB'
        END AS backup_size_unit
    ,t3.first_lsn
    ,t3.last_lsn
    ,CASE
        WHEN t3.differential_base_lsn IS NULL
            THEN 'Not Applicable'
        ELSE convert(VARCHAR(100), t3.differential_base_lsn)
        END AS [differential_base_lsn]
    ,t6.device_type AS [device_type]
    ,t3.recovery_model
FROM sys.databases t1
INNER JOIN backupset t3 ON (t3.database_name = t1.NAME)
LEFT JOIN backupmediaset t5 ON (t3.media_set_id = t5.media_set_id)
LEFT JOIN backupmediafamily t6 ON (t6.media_set_id = t5.media_set_id)
WHERE (t1.NAME = @DatabaseName)
ORDER BY t6.physical_device_name;
```

Now go to the person that gave you this backup and ask for the second part.